# Repetition in Python for each element of list

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have a list `a = [3,7,4]`

I want to generate a list repetition of a sequence generated from each element of list like that:

`b = [1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3]`

Comment: b=[]
for i in a:
        b.extend([i]*(i))

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try like this.

```
result = []
for i,j in enumerate(a):
    result += [i+1 for n in range(j)]
```

**Result**

```
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

Comment: We generally wait to see what askers come up with themselves before we throw the answer at them.

Comment: @DeepSpace Sorry. I didn't think much about it.

Comment: @DeepSpace Saw your comment now, that makes sense. (y)

Comment: i didnt do this @RahulKP.  i am so appreciated for your answer. also, i do not have any permission to vote now.

Comment: @YasinKÜTÜK Cool.

Answer (score -1):

input:

```
a = [3,7,4]
b = [x for x in range(len(a)+1)[1::] for j in range(a[x-1])]
```

result:

```
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```